# Calculate SUM Column Wise using dinaymic query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
 id varname 1area 2area 3area 4area
 ------------------------------------
 1   abc      345  3.7   34     87
 1   pqr      46    67   78     55 
 1   lmn      67   99    33     44 
 2   xyz      78    78    33    32
```

I need to calculate `SUM` of column query.

Is it possible to get column count using while loop?

Comment: and what would you result set look like?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a `SUM()` of the `Narea` column `group by` your `id` column like

```
select id, sum(1area),
sum(2area), sum(3area), sum(4area)
from tbl1
group by id;
```